# Learning c++, compilation error "no matching function for call"

Tags: c++

In the book Accelerated C+ I'm trying to run the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
std::cout << "Please enter  your name: ";
std::string name;
std::cin >> name;

const std::string greeting = "Hello, " + name + "!";


const std::string spaces(greeting.size(), " ");
const std::string second = "* " + spaces + " *";

const std::string first(second.size(), + "*");

std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << first << std::endl;
std::cout << second << std::endl;
std::cout << "* " << greeting << " *" << std::endl;
std::cout << second << std::endl;
std::cout << first << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

And its giving me a compilation error that says:

```
c:\Users\darkL\Desktop\cLearn\learnOne.cpp: In function 'int main()':
c:\Users\darkL\Desktop\cLearn\learnOne.cpp:15:47: error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type, const char [2])'
     const std::string first(second.size(), "*");
                                               ^
In file included from C:/Mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/string:52,
                 from C:/Mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from C:/Mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from C:/Mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from C:/Mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/Mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from c:\Users\darkL\Desktop\cLearn\learnOne.cpp:1:
C:/Mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:604:9: note: candidate: 'template<class _InputIterator, class> std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const _Alloc&)'
         basic_string(_InputIterator __beg, _InputIterator __end,
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:604:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
c:\Users\darkL\Desktop\cLearn\learnOne.cpp:15:47: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter '_InputIterator' ('unsigned int' and 'const char*')
     const std::string first(second.size(), "*");
                                                  ^
```

does that mean the size() function is not valid for greeting? or is spaces() not valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument for the `std::string` [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) needs to be a `char`, not a `string`:

```
const std::string spaces(greeting.size(), ' ');
```

You also need to do the same thing for the following line, and get rid of the `+` symbol:

```
const std::string first(second.size(), + "*");  // wrong
```

like this:

```
const std::string first(second.size(), '*');
```

Note that you *could* leave the `+` in there, but it doesn't do anything useful, and will be confusing to people reading your code, so you should avoid it.

Comment: Clear, concise, correct answer: nice! But, just for the sake of being whatever, `const std::string first(second.size(), + '*');` does actually work, even with the `+`, which is then taken as the unary "+" operator.

Comment: Im confused, I changed it std::string to char and it still says no matching function. Ok, Im gonna do a read up on the constructor link  you sent hopefully Ill have a better understanding

Comment: @AdrianMole edited the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: @BlueFits what error do you get? Did you use the code I showed in the answer? See the last example in the link that I shared, that's the one you're trying to use.

Comment: I put the error in detail, I fixed the first(second.size(), "*") but I might be defining my chars wrong, so you just do const char instead of const std::string?

Comment: @BlueFits No, see the answer closely. The type of the variable `first` is a `const std::string`, that part is fine. But the 2nd argument to the constructor needs to be a `char`, so `'*'`, instead of `"*"`.

Comment: Ohhh got it, ok gonna research my chars clearly i don't anything about this language